# Mail won't open anymore OS X El Capitan 10.11.5

Tags: email

I cannot get Mail to open everytime I accidentally try to open it it takes forever and never actually opens and then asks if I want to reindex or just reopen - I have tried both options with no results.  I usually have to force quit it as it just freezes everything.  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Can you give us some more details on your system? Which model Mac, how much free ram and CPU usage (check activity monitor), about how many emails are in your system, how many mail accounts you have, and if any of them are POP or if they are all IMAP with accessible web versions (so we could remove the accounts from Mail and add them again).

Comment: OK I know I am going to sound pretty stupid (I knew my PC way better than I know my Mac) but how do I find out any of this information? iMac (Late 2012 model)
It says Physical memory 8GB - Memory Used 6.08GB - I think I had about 5 emails going to Mail I have since deleted a couple and turned the rest to inactive before trying to open it but hasn't made a difference

Comment: You can find basic system information from the main Apple menu. To find the specifics I was wondering about like free RAM and how much your CPU is being used, search spotlight for Activity Monitor. Also how much free space do you have (it should say in the bottom of any Finder window)?

Comment: Going through finder it says 773.57GB available

Comment: Basically I just want to make sure that everything is okay and it's just some software issue. And I'm thinking the solution might end up being to remove all your email accounts through System Preferences and try seeing if mail works. Or I mean you could use Thunderbird.

Comment: Ok I'll give that a go.

Comment: I'm trying to delete one of my mail accounts and it has frozen system preferences (I'm guessing this one may be the culprit?) not sure how to proceed

Comment: Do you have a time machine backup from before the problem started? Maybe we can restore what's associated with Mail. Also, again, I'm curious, how large is your Mail inbox, how many emails have you gotten, and how much available RAM do you have? How much RAM does your iMac have? With El Capitan, 8GB is a good idea, especially if you don't have a SSD.

Comment: Yes I think so - but not sure how to use it

Comment: Just tried to restore mail to an earlier date but it says it won't let me modify it as it is required by OS X

Comment: to try and answer your questions I had lots of folders where I stored old emails when I look at Mail in Finder it says it is 40.7MB - is that what you mean or is there another way to check?

Comment: I don't mean restore the Mail app itself, but where in the Library or wherever it is that the mail is actually stored.

Comment: Try this: Open Finder, press Command+Shift+G and type in ~/Library and then select the Mail folder and restore it with Time Machine from a backup that was made before the problem started. But first do a new backup just in case this messes things up and you need to restore again to how things are right now. Please report back on if that fixes it. Also open Activity Monitor (find it using Spotlight) and tell me what it says in the Memory tab at the bottom under Physical Memory and Memory Used.

Comment: Actually, before you do the Time Machine restore, here's one other thing you can try: Go to http://www.computerworld.com/article/2991340/apple-mac/a-quick-guide-to-fixing-el-capitan-mail-problems.html and follow the steps under Stop the freeze

Answer (score 1):

OK I finally figured out how to fix it (yay).

I followed this http://c-command.com/spamsieve/help/how-can-i-rebuild-apple to delete the current index which then let me into Mail (finally) and get all my old emails back.  I am so happy to have it back. :-) Thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

OMG figured it out! Click and hold the Mail icon 
Then select "Inbox"[image]